# Selenium Webdriver continue through multiple classes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I made a test script that is way to long. So, i'm making short classes. if i want to run a few in a row (with TestNG xml file) the first class will succeed, but the next one opens a new firefox window because of:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

How do I make it so that it won't open a new window but goes on in the same window as the previous class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered many times before, but [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35116310/954442) I posted the other day. In a nutshell:

- Create singleton WebDriver at the start of your test run
- Reuse it in all your tests
- Don't close or quit it until you're finished.

Answer (score 2):

This might be workaround, you can used in you code,
    @AfterClass
    public closedBrowser()
    {
    driver.close();
    }

So that next class is opened freshly in new browser. Write a 'driver.close()' in After class.