# How to click on every link from a list of links? - Python, Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on one link from a list of links, wait one second (not added yet) and then click on the next link. Using selenium and bs4. This is my code:

```
links = ['https://www.bing.com', 'https://www.google.com', 'https://www.yahoo.com']
for url in links:
    url = "'"+url+"'"
    print(url,'\n')
    browser = webdriver.Firefox
    browser.get(url)
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SK/PycharmProjects/untitled/linkedin_bot.py", line 38, in <module>
    browser.get(url)
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

What exactly am I doing wrong and how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: You're creating a new browser instance for *every single request*? Here's why you might want to change that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35116310/954442

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `browser = webdriver.Firefox` to `browser = webdriver.Firefox()`.  As it is, when you call `browser.get(url)`, it is expecting a `webdriver.Firefox` instance as the first argument and a url as the second argument.  When you include the parentheses, you are creating an instance of `webdriver.Firefox` and Python automatically gives it as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the "url" variable name is the same as the "url" in the for loop.
Try renaming the variable.

Here is the amended code.
I have used Chrome as the driver, but you can use Firefox or any other driver.
Remember to change the executable path of the driver to match your situation.

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe')

links = ['https://www.bing.com', 'https://www.google.com', 'https://www.yahoo.com']
for url in links:
    urls = "'"+url+"'"
    print(urls,'\n')
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
```